# FXML layout not loaded when run jar outside Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, javafx, fxml

I try to load my fxml layout file as follows:

```
 FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
 loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("view/MainLayout.fxml"));
 AnchorPane personOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
```

When I run application in Eclipse all works, but when I deployed application with Ant, I've got an error:

[image]

After building project my folder structure is:

[image]

and the same in deployed jar

I understand that there might be a problem with difference in resolving path inside jar and in eclipse, but I can't resolve this.
I use Java 1.8 and JavaFX 8.

**UPDATE 1**
Accodring to the error I think it resolves path using absolute URL (starts with file:/C:/...), but should use relative url inside jar file. Why it use absolute path is main question.

**UPDATE 2**

Interesting that root layout loads successfully, with same code..

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
```

But inner layout initialization fails.

Stack trace:

```
java -jar MeterChecker.jar
javafx.fxml.LoadException: unknown path

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at com.wolf6969.checker.MainApp.showMain(Unknown Source)
at com.wolf6969.checker.MainApp.start(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/138227185.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/584634336.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/94326726.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/501263526.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/96639997.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.wolf6969.checker.service.SmsService.getCommandKeys(Unknown Source)
at com.wolf6969.checker.view.MainController.setupControls(Unknown Source)
at com.wolf6969.checker.view.MainController.initialize(Unknown Source)
... 27 more
Exception in Application stop method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application stop method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/752848266.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.wolf6969.checker.MainApp.stop(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$154(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$147/1418913435.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/584634336.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/94326726.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/501263526.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/96639997.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
Exception running application com.wolf6969.checker.MainApp
```

Comment: try using MainApp.class.getResource instead of getclass.getResource

Comment: tried, nothing changed. Perfectly works in eclipse, ant same error when jar executed.
Now I use following code:

`FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();`
`loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml");`

Comment: try running the jar from command prompt and post full trace

Comment: I've added stack trace in update 2

Comment: I log out URL created by getResource and it contains:
`jar:file:/C:/workspace/MeterChecker/build/deploy/bundles/MeterChecker/app/MeterChecker.jar!/com/wolf6969/checker/view/MainLayout.fxml`
Why it is absolute to location of jar not to classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using following code

```
 FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("views/MainFrame.fxml"));
 AnchorPane rootpane=(AnchorPane) loader.load();
```

and it is working as it should

**edit :** after looking at your trace I think problem is in your controller , try having a look at this 
[link](http://code.makery.ch/java/javafx-8-tutorial-part1/#comment-1564838301)

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.wolf6969.checker.service.SmsService.getCommandKeys(Unknown Source)
at com.wolf6969.checker.view.MainController.setupControls(Unknown Source)
at com.wolf6969.checker.view.MainController.initialize(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You right, the problem is that resource folder with some configuration files not copied to deploy directory. Thank you a lot! Now it works